# Set secure flag for cookies Symfony Azure

Tags: azure, cookies, web-config, symfony-3.4

I have to set the secure flag for my website cookies. My website is in Symfony 3.4 and it is deployed on Azure. I have tried this rule `<httpCookies requireSSL="true" httpOnlyCookies="true"/>` under `<system.webServer>` in  web.config file but it doesn't work and I tried adding this tag under `<system.web>` as well, but no luck.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have set it in my symphony configuration and got it sorted for those cookies which were created by my application. I didn't have to do it by web.config.

Set these below parameters in the `config.yml` file.

**config.yml**

```
framework:
    session:
        cookie_httponly: true
        cookie_secure: true
```